# Have scan before a fget

Tags: c, scanf

I use a

```
scanf("%d%d",&row,&col); // row & col is int
```

before

```
fgets(buf, MAXLEN, stdin); //MAXLEN == 65535 ; buf is char
```

I want to input buf after input row and col

but fgets will be skip

May someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the user's input?

Comment: Use fgets for both and move on to more important improvements. :)

Comment: You can use `fgets` in combinatin with `sscanf`. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58403955/6699433

Comment: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). Better not to mix the methods.

Answer (score 0):

[This issue can arise](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-with-scanf-when-there-is-fgetsgetsscanf-after-it/) if your input is on two separate lines. `scanf()` will leave a newline character in the buffer; when `fgets()` tries to read the remainder of the input, it will receive the newline character and stop reading. The following may fix your code:

`scanf("%d%d\n", &row, &col);`

This will read the newline in as well, leaving the rest for `fgets()`.

Comment: This will also read ALL whitespace after the second number, and won't return until a non-whitespace character is available on the input (which it will leave there).  This may be a problem in an interactive situation, for example if the program wants to print a prompt before the fgets -- it will appear to "hang" (no prompt will print) until a line with a non-whitepace character is entered.  At which point it will print the prompt and read the line entered just before the prompt.